# How to iterate through a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, api

I am making a server side API call. The user can input ingredients and search. When the data is submitted, I see on my terminal this as my API call:

"http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=[object Object]".

I am hoping for it to look like this:

"http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=milk,flour,sugar,egg"

Here is my code:

```
router.get("/whatCanIMake", function(request, response){

    var inputIngredients = request.query;
    var ingredientString = "";
    console.log(inputIngredients);
    for (var i = 0; i<inputIngredients.length; i++){
        ingredientString += inputIngredients[i] + ",";
    }

    var api = "http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=" + inputIngredients + "";
    console.log(api);
    console.log("inputingredients", inputIngredients);

    request.get(api, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}`

Comment: What is the content of `inputIngredients`? Is it simply a string array of the possible ingredients? Or is it an array of objects? It looks like objects. Without knowing those object's structure, then it's impossible to say which property to pull out for your query. So, we'll need to see the structure of `inputIngredients`.

Comment: This is what my terminal's console.log is for inputingredients { '0': 'milk', '1': 'sugar', '2': 'water', '3': 'flour' }

Comment: You are seeing `[object Object]` because you are appending `inputIngredients`, which is an array. You want to append `ingredientString`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Lodash _.forEach method:

https://lodash.com/docs#forEach

```
var ingredientString = "";

_.forEach(inputIngredients, function(value,key){

  if(ingredientString.length != ""){
    ingredientString += "," + value;
  }
  else {
    ingredientString = value;
  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
router.get("/whatCanIMake", function(request, response){

var inputIngredients = request.query;
var ingredientString = "";
console.log(inputIngredients);
//for (var i = 0; i<inputIngredients.length; i++){
//   ingredientString += inputIngredients[i] + ",";
//}

for (var property in inputIngredients)
{
 if (inputIngredients.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
 ingredientString += property + ",";
 }
}
```

//rest of your code here

Comment: I got this in my terminal as a return:

http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=[object Object]
inputingredients { '0': 'egg', '1': 'milk', '2': 'flour', '3': 'water' }

Comment: Why would this work? You're not even using `ingredientString` after generating it.

Comment: I noticed the same thing after I submitted this and changed it to this:

    var api = "http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=" + ingredientString + "";

I got this as a console.log:

console.log(http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=)

console.log(inputingredients { '0': 'egg', '1': 'butter', '2': 'milk' })

Comment: @Mike C yes sorry, I just rectified his iteration code and didn't check the whole code. I thought that he is facing problems with getting that code.